# Can I use concat with toString?

Tags: android, tostring, concatenation

I'm trying to add a new line ("\n") to a string at the same time as I'm converting a TextView to a string. When the user clicks the "Save Name" button it adds a name that is generated and displayed in the TextView. He then can choose to generate another name and click save again. When I'm later displaying the saved names I want them to be on seperate lines, not right after each other.
This is my code:

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Save Name button */
public void save_name(View view) {

    String filename = "saved_names.txt";
    TextView inputName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tViewName);
    String name = inputName.getText().toString().concat("\n");
    FileOutputStream outputStream;

    try {
      outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_APPEND);
      outputStream.write(name.getBytes());
      outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, it's still on the same line. What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. The code above is correct:

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Save Name button */
public void save_name(View view) {

    String filename = "saved_names.txt";
    TextView inputName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tViewName);
    String name = inputName.getText().toString().concat("\n");
    FileOutputStream outputStream;

    try {
      outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_APPEND);
      outputStream.write(name.getBytes());
      outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I also needed to add the "\n" on the code where I read from the file to display the names:

```
private String readFromFile() {
    String ret = "";
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = openFileInput("saved_names.txt");

        if ( inputStream != null ) {
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            String receiveString = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while ( (receiveString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null ) {
                stringBuilder.append(receiveString + "\n");
            }

            inputStream.close();
            ret = stringBuilder.toString();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "File not found: " + e.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Can not read file: " + e.toString());
    }

    return ret;
}
```

On this line: `stringBuilder.append(receiveString + "\n");`

Thank you for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `\r\n` (carriage return, line break) instead of just `\n` if you're writing it to a file and reading it back in.

Comment: Ok, so you mean that I should use append instead of concat? Yes I am writing and reading a file.

Comment: Sorry, the important part is to just use `\r\n` instead of `\n`.

Comment: Tried this: String name = inputName.getText().toString().concat("\r\n"); Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

First, set your TextView to disable [singeLine](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3asingleLine) mode. By default, TextViews have singleLine set to true.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="false" />
```

Second, you aren't actually setting the TextView's content; you simply get the current contents and append a newline to that String object (not the TextView).

What you want is:

```
TextView inputName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tViewName);
String name = inputName.getText().toString().concat("\n");
inputName.setText(name);
```

You may also want to consider using a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html) for your list of names, as they provide much better support for adding, removing, and styling items

Comment: Tried this, but didn't work. Also, what should I use instead of getText if I use ListView, because I get an error on that too.

Comment: If you use a ListView, you need to call getText() on a TextView inside the ListView, not the ListView itself. ListViews contain other Views. That being said, I believe I found the actual problem with your original code, and updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: This only added a new line to the textview where the generated name is displayed. The saved names are still on the same line. What I actually want to do is to add the next generated name on a new line, in the string that is saved to the file. But thanks for helping me figure this out!